# can't play/download MP4 files from behind .htaccess on mobile device such as android / blackberry

Tags: .htaccess, video, mobile, mp4

I have made a site with a password protected directory and
 inside is simple html page with link to mp4 video file located inside directory.

When logged into to directory Android device such as Samsung Galaxy S2 or Blackberry Playbook fail to open this video file. On desktop , IE and FF work fine.

this is response from host:

> "It appears this is a limitation of the browsers in mobile devices being unable to use the authentication that has already been completed to fetch the video file using the embeded player. After investigating in depth I am unable to get any other player to play video on my mobile device if it is behind a .htaccess password protection since the requests for the actual video file are being denied with 403."

So what is solution to play Mp4 behind htaccess on mobile device?

Comment: I am facing exact same problem did you find the solution?

Comment: your help is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing one way to do it is that the link should be not to the file directly but should trigger a small module that will give permissions to the file for the client ip that has just connected then redirect to the file. The permissions can be retracted sometime later. But it feels messy and am not really sure if this is scalable at huge traffic levels.